# Override rails config during precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

During `assets:precompile`, I want to override `config.threadsafe!` (setting it to false), but otherwise I want to use all the config from `production.rb`. Is there an easy way to override a single property? I'd like to avoid duplicating `production.rb` into a new custom environment, since `threadsafe!` is the only property that's different.

**Update**: you can't "unset" `threadsafe!`, so I'll probably just need to set `config. allow_concurrency = false`.

Comment: To what end?  I'm not questioning your reasons, I'm just curious as to what this will accomplish.

Comment: I run my app in JRuby, but I precompile under MRI in order to use node for lesscss compilation, since Rhino is so slow that it's basically unusable (something like 2 minutes vs 20 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit environments:

```
eval File.read("#{Rails.root}/..../production.rb")
```